# Call to undefined function App\Transaksi()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a problem with my coding, i want to count user on my database but it's appear to be like this

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to undefined function App\Transaksi()**

Here's my index.php

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
<!-- small box -->
<div class="small-box bg-aqua">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>{{ $list->transaksi }}</h3>

    <p>Transaksi</p>
  </div>
```

and my controller.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BackController extends Controller
{
public function list()
{

$transaksi = \App\Transaksi::get();
$transaksi = \App\Transaksi('id')->count();

 return view('/admin', compact('list'));
 }

}
```

and my routes

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'user','middleware' => ['auth', 'role:member']],
function (){
    Route::get('/mybook','FrontController@mybook');
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin']], function(){


Route::get('/',function() {
  return view('admin.index');
});
Route::get('/','BackController@list');
Route::get('logout','UserController@logout');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry For the late reply main bug in your list function is

```
public function list()
{

$transaksi = \App\Transaksi::get();
$transaksi = \App\Transaksi('id')->count();

 return view('/admin', compact('list'));
 }
```

You are Using the Same varible name to

Retrive all the records  `$transaksi = \App\Transaksi::get();`  and 
also for the Counting all the records `$transaksi = \App\Transaksi('id')->count();`

and also you are not passing it to the balde viewer

instead You are passing the function name `list`

```
return view('/admin', compact('list'));
```

**Solution To you problem**

First you need not to write  `\App\Transaksi` in every where

Just Go to the top of the controller and add this line

```
use App\Transaksi;
```

Then Your function

There are several ways to count the record

**Method 1:**

```
public function list()
{
   $transaksi= Transaksi::latest()->paginate(10);
   return view('transaksi.index', compact('transaksi'));
}
```

here `view('transaksi.index')` refers to

```
Projectname/resources/views/transaksi/index.blade.php
```

Then in your  index.blade.php to get the count just use the code

```
<h3 class="modal-title">{{ $transaksi->total() }} {{ str_plural('Transaksi', $transaksi->count()) }} </h3>
```

**Method 2:**

```
public function list()
    {
        $transaksi  = Transaksi::latest()->get();
        $recordCount = Transaksi::count();
        return view('transaksi.index', compact('transaksi','recordCount'));
    }
```

Then in your blade file

```
<h3>{{ $recordCount }}</h3>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your complete guide for my mistake, it's work as i try now, i'm still a beginner on laravel your help means everything to me thanks once more.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller isn't doing much right now. The view needs to be a valid blade template file, e.g. `admin.index`, not `/admin`. You then need to pass a variable into the view, not the function name.

```
public function list()
{

    $transaksi = \App\Transaksi::all();
    $numTransaksi = $transaksi->count();

    return view('admin.index', compact('numTransaksi'));
}
```

Then in the view you can access the count via `{{ $numTransaksi }}`.

You also have two routes for `/` in your `web.php`. You should get rid of the first one if you want the `BackController@list` function to call properly.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm still new to laravel, i will learn your advice next time thank you once more.